# Wrapper Test Class Code Coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test, wrapper-class

I have a wrapper class i tried test code coverage till 76% ,i am trying to make it 100%:

Wrapper Class:

```
public class wrapperClassController {
    public List<Product_Details__c > pd1 {get;set;} 
    public List<prod> productlist {get;set;}
    public List<Product__c > selectedproducts {get;set;}
    public prod te {get;set;}

    //This method uses a simple SOQL query to return a List of Contacts
    public List<prod> getproducts(){
        if(productlist==null)
        {
            productlist=new List<prod>();
            // As each contact is processed we create a new cContact object and add it to the contactList
            for(Product__c p1: [select Name,Product_Description__c,Product_Family__c,Range__c,Rate_Per_Sq_Mtrs__c from Product__c])
            {
                te=new prod(p1,false);
                productlist.add(te);   
            }     
       }
       return productlist;
    }

    public PageReference proceedToConfigure() 
    { 
        Opportunity__C opp1=[select Id,name from Opportunity__C where   id=:apexpages.currentpage().getParameters().get('Id')];     
        selectedproducts = new List<Product__c >();   
        for(prod p:productlist ) {
            if(p.selected == true) {
                selectedproducts.add(p.pr); //This is not covered in test class
            }
        }  

        pd1 = new List<Product_Details__c >();
        for(prod p1:productlist ){
            if(p1.selected == true) {      
                Product_Details__c pd= new Product_Details__c(); //This is not covered
                pd.Dimension__c='1';
                pd.name=p1.pr.name;
                pd.Units__c= 'none';
                pd.Rate_Per_Sq_Mtr1__c=null;
                pd.Product__c= p1.pr.id;
                pd.Opportunity__c= opp1.id;                      
                pd1.add(pd);                  
            }                                     
        }
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/configureprdoucts');        
        return pageRef;
    }    
    public pagereference save(){
        Opportunity__C opp13=[select Id,name from Opportunity__C where Opportunity__C.id=:apexpages.currentpage().getParameters().get('Id')];  
        insert pd1;
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('https://cs31.salesforce.com/'+ opp13.Id);        
        return pageRef;
    }

    //Wrapper class for product   
    public class Prod {
        public Product__c pr {get;set;}
        public Opportunity__c opp {get;set;} //this is not covered
        public Boolean selected {get;set;}   
        public prod(Product__c p,boolean s){
            pr=p;
            selected=s;
        }
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class Testproductwrapper{
    static testmethod void prod_wrap(){
        Opportunity__c op=new Opportunity__c();
        op.Close_Date__c=system.Today();
        insert op;
        Product__c p=new Product__c();
        p.name='afs';
        insert p;
        Product_Details__c Pd=new Product_Details__c();
        Pd.name='Test';
        pd.Product__c=p.id;
        pd.Rate_Per_Sq_Mtr1__c=2;
        pd.Opportunity__c=op.id;
        insert pd;
        Boolean b=false;
        PageReference pRef = Page.addproduct1;
        pRef.getParameters().put('id', op.Id);
        Test.setCurrentPage(pRef);
        Test.startTest();
        wrapperClassController wc=new wrapperClassController();
        wc.getproducts();   
        wc.proceedToConfigure();
        wc.save();
        wrapperClassController.Prod pr=new wrapperClassController.Prod(p,b); 
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) Why are you not using OOTB `Opportunity` and `Product2` ? (2) hard-coded sandbox page references will be an issue (3) no asserts in test class - hence not really proving anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lines are not covered because none of your products are selected.

Your code does this:

```
te=new prod(p1,false);
productlist.add(te);
```

Essentially, `productlist` contains a list of `prod` instances that are not selected. In order to make it go through that `if` condition, you need to select at least one selected product.

Your test code, after calling `wc.getproducts()` should do:

```
wc.productlist[0].selected = true;
```

To select the first item in the list.

That should cover the first 2 missing items.

In order to cover the 3rd one, after calling this:

```
wrapperClassController.Prod pr=new wrapperClassController.Prod(p,b);
```

Add this line:

```
pr.opp = op;
```

That will give you the coverage. However, I would suggest a couple of fixes to improve the code and the tests:

- Do you really need to test the wrapper class which just has a bunch of properties? It has no business logic, so I would not test it
- If you really want to cover it, I would move the coverage for the 'Prod' class to a different test method
- I would create a new constructor for `Prod` that takes the opportunity as an argument.

It could look like this:

```
public prod(Product__c p,boolean s, Opportunity o){
    pr=p;
    selected=s;
    opp = o;
}
```

That could make testing the class a bit easier